# Google Home integration with cordova App

Tags: cordova, dialogflow-es, google-home

I want to use `Google Home` to send messages and receive messages to a web server. Is it possible to use api.ai to send messages to a `Cordova App` which will then communicate with the web server and then return the message from the web server to the user via google home.

Right now I was able to find `api-ai-cordova` plugin which allows you to communicate via voice with the app only through the phone, but I want to communicate with the App using Google Home.

Is there a way to integrate a `Google Home` and `Cordova App`?